# How to add more items to the new Windows 11 context menu?

Tags: windows, registry

is there any way to add new items to windows 11 context menu? I can't find a key to which I can insert shortcuts like I did in windows 10

```
Windows 10
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ Directory \ Background \ shell


Windows 11
?
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like you can use the registry to extend the new menu, this might be relevant: https://blogs.windows.com/blog/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/#:~:text=Apps%20extend%20the%20menu%20with%20IExplorerCommand

Comment: Thank you, "Apps extend the menu with IExplorerCommand + app identity" It's harder than I thought

Comment: @JuanDavid Being hard is the point, Microsoft has done this on purpose. You also need to sign the package and that kills all small developers.

Comment: Does it allow self-signed certs?